# Правильно ли расставлены запятые перед оборотом «буквально ввалившись»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, деепричастный-оборот, и

*— Наконец-то я дома, — радостно воскликнул Александр, открыв ключом дверь, и, буквально ввалившись в квартиру, набросил куртку на крючок.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пунктуация верная.
*...**воскликнул** Александр, открыв ключом дверь, **и,** буквально ввалившись в квартиру, **набросил** куртку на крючок.*

Здесь деепричастные обороты относятся к разным глаголам и обособляются с двух сторон. Убрав обороты, мы соединим сказуемые: *воскликнул **и** набросил*. Если бы не было последней части со вторым сказуемым, то запятая не ставилась бы, союз ***и*** соединил бы деепричастия:
*...воскликнул Александр, **открыв** ключом дверь **и** буквально **ввалившись** в квартиру.*

> **2.** Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения).

[Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113) (справочник Розенталя)

**P. S.** Если Александр *воскликнул* (да ещё *радостно*), я бы поставил соответствующий знак:
— *Наконец-то я дома!*

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания верные, вот только **стилистика и графика** вызывает вопросы. **Четыре действия** в одном предложении? Поэтому и правильная пунктуация не смотрится.

Вариант **редактирования**:

*— Наконец-то я дома! — радостно **воскликнул** Александр. **Открыв** ключом дверь, он буквально **ввалился** в квартиру и **набросил** куртку на крючок.*